# Using MPU9250 / 6500 with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, mpu6050

The senson is detected when I do `i2cdetect -y 1`

But I cannot find any tutorial regarding MPU9250/6500 for RPi4. All I get is of MPU6050.. so can I use the 6050's libraries? Also almost every guide out there is mostly for Pico using MicroPython.
Please guide me how to get this running. Or just point me to any suitable library of it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://invensense.tdk.com/developers/software-downloads/ Look on right side bottom.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Hi, thanks for replying. What are you referring to exactly.. The MPU section? Correct me if im wrong but this seems like a totally different sensor

Comment: You can use 6050's libraries.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Are you sure? Okay that solves everything! You may post the answer if you want

Comment: One of my got it working without using library. I am waiting for my part.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yessss i think i've seen that one too. But doesn't it get fairly inaccurate without the libs? (Since you are not posting answer i've upvote another answer of yours. Thanks!)

Comment: Is your chip alone or come with board? If alone, you write a driver. If comes with board, don't need library.

Comment: @toyotaSupra With a board (added img) Oh okay so i can directly use the i2c commands. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Yes that is. sudo pip install FaBo9Axis_MPU9250 Here is link https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-interface-an-imu-sensor-with-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: @toyotaSupra sorry if i sound noob but isn't that arduino lib? With RPi is it same?

Comment: @toyotaSupra OKAY that's exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot! Honestly. Please post it as an answer. You helped a lot :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is link for  [Sensor MPU9250 With Raspberry Pi](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-interface-an-imu-sensor-with-a-raspberry-pi)